# Javascript 'new Date()' shows incorrect locale time? (7 hours late)

Tags: javascript, date

Directly as the titles says,
I tried `new Date()` on my app, even on an online editor.
And the result was an incorrect value of time and day (7 hours late). Other than that the Greenwich Mean Time that is shown is actually correct (GMT + 7). So at the time, I wrote this.

[image: Proof]

That is an online Javascript editor that can be found [here](https://jscomplete.com/playground). And if you look at the top-right, that's the time of my local computer. And the **correct** date and time. However, the code editor says otherwise. I tried it on my local computer too using `nodejs`. But it's the same result.

**The Question**

1. Is this a bug?
2. How do I get the accurate time and date for my application without the help of a library?

Thank you.

Comment: works fine, must be your computer that's wrong if both that site and node.js display the wrong time

Comment: *7 hours earlier* ... looks more like 7 hours later ... open your browsers developer tools console ... what does `console.log(new Date().toString())` and `console.log(new Date().toISOString())` and `console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())` output

Comment: U may have set a correct hour on your computer, BUT not the correct meridian configuration ( for instance, your computer is on GMT +1 but your country GMT -6, and you have manually changed the time ).

Comment: @JaromandaX oops, yes, sorry will fix that, the output at the current time I writing this, `Mon Sep 30 2019 02:47:59 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)`, `2019-09-29T19:47:59.677Z`, `-420`

Comment: `2019-09-29T19:47:59.677Z` ... well, 24 minutes ago when you wrote that, it was more like `2019-09-29T12:47:50.677Z` - so, since UTC time is out, there's a problem with the clock in your system - that doesn't look like Windows or MacOS to me, is it some Linux distro you're running?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it's Linux. I have noted what `iguypouf` said, and still looking for a solution, but since I already noticed it I will probably do it later because I'm on work right now. Thanks!